# PHP-SSH codes to connect to a router

Tags: php, html, ssh

i am working on a project which requires me to connect into my company's IP network. I earlier used telnet for a router but the other routers in the network are configured with SSH, 
Please can someone help me with the PHP-SSh codes so that i can connect an read the configurations on a webpage?

Comment: welcome to SO, please take a quick look at [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to make it easier for us to help you, Good luck.

Comment: ok let me rephrase, SSH codes to connect to a router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ssh2 extension: http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

For example:

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($conn, $login, $password);
$stream = ssh2_exec($conn, "/bin/ls -l /");
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$result = stream_get_contents($stream);
```

Comment: These codes are taking too long to execute can someone prepose something else